# how to check if 1 player has played another

Tags: php, mysql

Im having issues performing a select on a table, but using the results of another table to filter the possibilities.

I have a table of player results (player id, wins, losses, draws, points), and rounds for the tournament are in another table (round id, tournament id, player 1 id, player 2 id and table id).

I've been trying to get a select statement that checks the tournamentround table and prevents the player from playing previous opponents (like a swiss tournament), but I run into the fact the player it choses for the second may then be chosen for another player.

ie p1 has played p2 and p3, but not p4 or p5, when the select happens it assigns p1 to p4, but when it gets to p4 it assigns p4 to p2.

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Example select:

```
SELECT * FROM playerresults WHERE ((SELECT pid FROM playerresults) != (SELECT p1id FROM tournamentrounds))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data in a *table* format as well as desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a given player, say `@playerid`, then you can get players that have not been played by doing something like:

```
select pr.*
from playerresults pr
where pr.pid not in (select t.pid2 from tournaments t where pid1 = @playerid) and
      pr.pid not in (select t.pid1 from tournaments t where pid2 = @playerid)
```

If you want a random one and your data is not very large (less than a few thousand rows), just add:

```
order by rand()
limit 1
```

to the query.